# Limit the width of the page to only half size of the browser

Tags: css

I'm currently learning web design and I was solving some sample problems online, there was one specific case when I was asked to:

1. Write a CSS rule that limits the width of the webpage to only half the size of the browser and centers it in the browser window.
2. Add a CSS rule, to the rule above , to display a green background color that  fills all the browser window including the empty left and right sides.

For 2, I could use this:

```
body {
    background-color: green;
}
```

But for 1, I couldn't do it. How do I get the size of the browser? It sounds confusing.

Comment: You could use `html,body{width:50% !important; margin: 0 auto}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this CSS to your body-

```
body{
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden; //just in case if you don't want your any fixed width element crosses the body width.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is set `width: 50%;`

Or if you want to set to maximum of 50%, use `max-width: 50%;`

To center, set `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`

Answer (score 1):

this is very easy just one step you have to take **try this**

```
body {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; //optional if you want your page in center
}
```